# Flutter local_auth с использованием системного диалогового окна биометрии

Tags: android, flutter, fingerprint

Всем добрый день, у меня проблема с отображением диалогового окна при запросе биометрии при входе в приложение Flutter.
Мне нужно использовать вид, который есть в системе по умолчанию, но плагин не дает этого сделать (либо, скорее всего, я плохо искал).
Понятнее будет на картинках:
1,2 картинки - так, как должно быть
3 картинка - так, как у меня.

Есть какие-нибудь варианты? Это должно быть возможно, скорее всего, ответ прост, но я пока не решил проблему.

Плагин local_auth: https://pub.dev/packages/local_auth

[image: Сравнение диалоговых окон]

Answer (score 0):

У данного плагина можно поменять только [текст сообщений](https://pub.dev/documentation/local_auth/latest/auth_strings/AndroidAuthMessages-class.html). Данный плагин использует стандартный дизайн предлагаемый ОС (по умолчанию) и изменять его нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен. Всё дело оказалось в версии самого плагина. У меня стояла версия 0.4, а последняя - 0.6.
На последней версии он также использует системный стандартный дизайн, только сам дизайн обновленный.
Будьте внимательны при импорте плагинов)